# Android: Images are stored at the end of the gallery

Tags: java, android, image, gallery, mediastore

can somebody help me with this problem?
I want that images are displayed at the beginning of the gallery.
What have i to change in my code?

```
 OutputStream fOut = null;
 try {   
   String path = getFilesDir().getPath();
   File file = new File(path, "LT-IMG-"+ts+".jpg"); 
   fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)photoView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
   fOut.flush();
   fOut.close(); 

   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

 } catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: What is the problem (error message in the stackstrace, for example) with your code? Also, when providing code, please make sure to provide a minimal, yet complete and verifiable piece of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

The former code will add the image at the end of the gallery. If you want to modify the date so it appears at the beginning or any other metadata, see the code below (Cortesy of S-K, samkirton):

https://gist.github.com/samkirton/0242ba81d7ca00b475b9

```
/**
* Android internals have been modified to store images in the media 
folder with * the correct date meta data * @author samuelkirton*/
public class CapturePhotoUtils {

/**
 * A copy of the Android internals  insertImage method, this method populates the 
 * meta data with DATE_ADDED and DATE_TAKEN. This fixes a common problem where media 
 * that is inserted manually gets saved at the end of the gallery (because date is not populated).
 * @see android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage(ContentResolver, Bitmap, String, String)
 */
public static final String insertImage(ContentResolver cr, 
        Bitmap source, 
        String title, 
        String description) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
    values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
    values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());

    Uri url = null;
    String stringUrl = null;    /* value to be returned */

    try {
        url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        if (source != null) {
            OutputStream imageOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
            try {
                source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imageOut);
            } finally {
                imageOut.close();
            }

            long id = ContentUris.parseId(url);
            // Wait until MINI_KIND thumbnail is generated.
            Bitmap miniThumb = Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
            // This is for backward compatibility.
            storeThumbnail(cr, miniThumb, id, 50F, 50F,Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        } else {
            cr.delete(url, null, null);
            url = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (url != null) {
            cr.delete(url, null, null);
            url = null;
        }
    }

    if (url != null) {
        stringUrl = url.toString();
    }

    return stringUrl;
}

/**
 * A copy of the Android internals StoreThumbnail method, it used with the insertImage to
 * populate the android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage with all the correct
 * meta data. The StoreThumbnail method is private so it must be duplicated here.
 * @see android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media (StoreThumbnail private method)
 */
private static final Bitmap storeThumbnail(
        ContentResolver cr,
        Bitmap source,
        long id,
        float width, 
        float height,
        int kind) {

    // create the matrix to scale it
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    float scaleX = width / source.getWidth();
    float scaleY = height / source.getHeight();

    matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);

    Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0,
        source.getWidth(),
        source.getHeight(), matrix,
        true
    );

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    values.put(Images.Thumbnails.KIND,kind);
    values.put(Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,(int)id);
    values.put(Images.Thumbnails.HEIGHT,thumb.getHeight());
    values.put(Images.Thumbnails.WIDTH,thumb.getWidth());

    Uri url = cr.insert(Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    try {
        OutputStream thumbOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
        thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, thumbOut);
        thumbOut.close();
        return thumb;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The order in which a gallery app shows images is up to the developers of the gallery (and, secondarily, the user). This code provides more metadata, which may affect how some gallery apps display it. However, it will not "ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery".

Comment: In very few cases it might not reflect as you said it depends on the developer of the gallery. But it surely would work on the gallery which would sort the images based on date.